# How to hide a function in a header file in C?

Tags: c, function, header, macros

Let's suppose that there are lib.c and lib.h.

```
//lib.c
int foo(int a, int flag);   // some function
int boo(void)               // some other function that calls 
{
    ...
    foo(a, flag);
}
```

The flag variable is important for the implementation, but it's better to hide this detail and have only `foo(int a)` in the header. The best way I know is to write

```
//lib.h
#define foo(a)    foo(a, MY_FLAG)
extern int foo(int a, int flag);
```

It works well, but I'd like somehow to get rid of the extern line completely, so whoever would use the library won't get confused. However, without this line gcc complains about an implicit declaration.
Ideally, I'd like to have something like this

```
//lib.c
#define foo(a)    foo(a, MY_FLAG)
int foo(int a, int flag);
int boo(void);
```

```
//lib.h
extern int foo(int a);   // all I want them to know
```

So how can something similar be done?

**EDIT1**
busybee's solution is to define a wrapper function in lib.c like so:

```
//lib.c
int foo(int a, int flag);   // the private function
int boo{int a}              // the public function
{
    return foo(a, SOME_FLAG);
}
...
```

```
//lib.h
extern int boo(int a);
```

Can anyone do better than that? Is it even possible?

Comment: But optional parameters are not supported in C, so if the implementation has 2 parameters, the caller must provide them...

Comment: The question isn't about the optional parameters specifically. It's about one or more ways to hide a function in a header.

Comment: In that case why not using a static declaration in the implementation and nothing in the header ?

Comment: Hiding it from the user also means hiding it from the compiler, so not possible..

Comment: dspr, because the function is for the public use, except for that flag argument. Declaring it static will make it unavailable.

Comment: Why do you want `foo()` to have two parameters, if the public interface may only use the first one? Can't you remove the second parameter? -- Another idea is to insert a "wrapper" that takes just one parameter and its implementation calls the "real" function with both parameters. Then you can hide the two-parameter function.

Comment: the busybee, I need this function to take two parameters for the implementation to work. The wrapper idea is the solution that I was looking for. It's not ideal as it costs a function call overhead, but it's the best we have. Anyways, since this is the best solution so far, I'd like to thank you and encourage to post it as an answer.

Comment: *It's not ideal as it costs a function call overhead*  And you've profiled your application, **measured** that overhead, and found that it actually matters?

Comment: Even if it doesn't matter for the current application, I'd still  like to know if a better solution exists.

Comment: There might be no overhead from the extra function call. If `bar(a)` is just a call to `foo(a, SOME_FLAG)`, an optimizing compiler likely will inline it.  Try your code at godbolt.org with gcc or clang with `-O2` or higher and inspect the disassembled output.